# Running background program on Windows Server

Tags: php, windows, hosting, exec, shell-exec

We have a windows program that does the following automatically when run:

When started, checks for new files in a directory to process.
If a new file is found, scrapes specific web data based on file.
Outputs new data into a file in another directory.

We are looking to create a web app using PHP that uploads files into the first directory and uses `exec()` to run the program in the background. Will a windows server allow us to run the program in the background until it finishes processing? And will it allow a program to connect to websites to scrape data?

Answer (score 0):

From [a users note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#35731) in the beloved PHP Manual:

```
pclose(popen("start \"bla\" \"" . $exe . "\" " . escapeshellarg($args), "r"));
```

Comment: What type of hosting solution would allow this? I'm looking at a Windows VPS with RDP.

Comment: That's a standard popen using the windows `start` command which allows to execute stuff in the background. Just open a cmd at the windows vps and try if start is available. It should be.